# how to validate Regex for text fields in jsp using java script

Tags: javascript, regex, jsp

Can anyone please help me in doing `firstname` validation using regex. 
In the below javascript code `if value.length==0` the error is properly generated.
But even after giving correct firstname format as in regex its throwing error as First name invalid. 
I have doubt on my else if block please help me

Java Script code is as below

```
function validate(){
            var valid = true;
            var regex="([A-Za-z]{3,30}\s*)";

        if (document.getElementById('fname').value.length == 0) {
        validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - First name is missing\r\n';
        document.getElementById('errorFirstNameMissing').style.visibility='visible';
        valid = false;
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('fname').value!=regex){
            validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - First name is not valid can contain   
only letters from A-z and a-z\r\n';
            document.getElementById('errorFirstNameInValid').style.visibility='visible';
            valid = false;
            }
        else{
            document.getElementById('errorFirstNameMissing').style.visibility='hidden';
            document.getElementById('errorFirstNameInValid').style.visibility='hidden';
        }

        if (valid == false){
        alert(validationMessage);
        }
        return valid;
        }
```

and my jsp is code is as below

```
<form name="Register" action="RegisterServlet" method="post" onSubmit="return validate()">
<table>
<tr>
<td>First Name* : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtFname" id="fname" maxlength="30"/><br/>
<span id="errorFirstNameMissing" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first 
name.</span><br/>
<span id="errorFirstNameInValid" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide a valid first 
name.</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex is not tested like that, you can use:

```
/^([A-Za-z]{3,30}$)/.test(name)
```

Read up on the regex object at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)